# Storing a select into a variable for future use in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

Im coding a procedure where i have to do an update with a "where field IN (SET)" condition. I am trying to retrieve this "SET" from a table with the following query :

```
   SELECT WM_CONCAT(fieldX) FROM TableX WHERE .... ;
```

I would like to save this select into a variable and use it after for the "where field IN (SET)" condition. Something like :

```
   UPDATE TABLEY SET ... WHERE fieldX IN (Variable);
```

Right now im get this error when i try to do a select with a where condition like the one i want for the update :

```
  ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
  00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try with xmltable,

```
UPDATE TABLEY y
SET ... 
WHERE y.fieldX IN(SELECT (COLUMN_VALUE).getNumberVal() 
                  FROM xmltable(Variable));
```

Comment: I want to avoid doing a query for every update. That is why i wanted to store the select inside a variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UPDATE TABLEY y
   SET ... 
 WHERE y.fieldX IN (
          SELECT x.fieldX FROM TableX x WHERE .... 
       )
     ;
```

Comment: Again, i dont like doing a select for every update when it is for the same data. Is there any way i can store this select into a variable for later use to prevent repeating the same query over and over? Thanks.

Comment: note that a database table actually _is_ kind of a variable holding data for later use. therefore you may harness temporary tables for intra-session storage. another way to go are the plsql colleciton data structures, most of which are mapped to tables anyway. still you might be better off repeating the query unless you can be certain that the underlying data does not change between successive invocations.